# ionic/cordova cannot create plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

i have problem with creation of my own plugin in ionic framework.

This is my plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" id="org.apache.cordova.hid" version="0.0.1">
  <name>Hid</name>
  <description>Cordova HID USB Plugin</description>
  <license>Apache 2.0</license>
  <keywords>cordova,hid</keywords>
  <js-module src="www/hid.js" name="hid">
    <clobbers target="hid" />
  </js-module>
</plugin>
```

This is my hid.js file that contains testing code:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

var hid = {
  testFunc : function(callback) {
    callback('echo echo');
  }
}
module.exports = hid;
```

I installed plugin to project using add:

```
$ ionic plugin add ./hid-plugin
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Saving plugin to package.json file
```

Then it appeared in my project in plugins folder.

This is my controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);

  // HERE IS THE TESTFUNC
  hid.testFunc(function(echoValue) {
    alert(echoValue);
  });
});
```

And this results into an error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 ReferenceError: hid is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:23:5)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17770:27)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22326:28
    at self.appendViewElement (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56883:24)
    at Object.switcher.render (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54995:41)
    at Object.switcher.init (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54915:20)
    at self.render (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56743:14)
    at self.register (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56701:10)
    at updateView (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62357:23) <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats" class="view-container tab-content" nav-view="active" nav-view-transition="android">
```

I tried almost everything:

- create function in hid.js without hid wrapping object
- put hid object into parameters of ChatDetailCtrl
- use $hid instead of hid

but without positive result.

Can you point to me what I've missed or done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. import you js file into index.html
2. look and check your cordova_plugins.js file (you can update it here)